# filter DATE lesser than (+30 days) than other DATE

Tags: r

I have two columns of date (listed in this format 2001-01-01) (DATE1 and DATE2). I want to filter all observations where DATE1(+30 days) < DATE2.

I´ve been trying: filter(DF, (DATE1+30) < DATE2))

but it doesn´t work.

Best regards,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `DATE1` and `DATE2` are already of class Date, you can do :

```
subset(df, (DATE2 - DATE1) < 30)
```

and similarly with `filter` :

```
dplyr::filter(df, (Date2 - Date1) < 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `[` method in `base R`

```
df[with(df, (DATE2 - DATE1) < 30),]
```